# How to train Tensorflow's pre trained BERT on MLM task? ( Use pre-trained model only in Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp, huggingface-transformers

Before Anyone suggests `pytorch` and other things, I am looking specifically for **Tensorflow** + **pretrained** + **MLM** task only. I know, there are lots of blogs for `PyTorch` and lots of blogs for fine tuning ( Classification) on Tensorflow.

Coming to the problem, I got a language model which is English + LaTex where a text data can represent any text from Physics, Chemistry, MAths and Biology and any typical example can look something like this:
[Link to OCR image](https://docs.mathpix.com/#process-an-image)

```
"Find the value of function x in the equation: \n \\( f(x)=\\left\\{\\begin{array}{ll}x^{2} & \\text { if } x<0 \\\\ 2 x & \\text { if } x \\geq 0\\end{array}\\right. \\)"
```

So my language model needs to understand `\geq \\begin array \eng \left \right` other than the English language and that is why I need to train an `MLM` first on pre-trained `BERT` or  [`SciBERT`](https://www.kaggle.com/gcspkmdr/scibert-tf2-tpu)  to have both. So I went up digging the internet and found some tutorials:

1. [`MLM` training on `Tensorflow` BUT from Scratch; I need pre-trained](https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/nlp/ipynb/masked_language_modeling.ipynb)
2. [`MLM` on pre-trained but in `Pytorch`; I need `Tensorflow`](https://towardsdatascience.com/masked-language-modelling-with-bert-7d49793e5d2c)
3. [Fine Tuning with Keras; It is for classification but I want `MLM`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training#finetuning-with-keras)

I already have a fine tuning classification model. Some of the code is as follows:

```
tokenizer = transformers.BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-large-uncased')

def regular_encode(texts, tokenizer, maxlen=maxlen):
  enc_di = tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(texts,  return_token_type_ids=False,padding='max_length',max_length=maxlen,truncation = True,)
  return np.array(enc_di['input_ids'])

Xtrain_encoded = regular_encode(X_train.astype('str'), tokenizer, maxlen=maxlen)
ytrain_encoded = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=classes,dtype = 'int32')

def build_model(transformer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', max_len=maxlen, dense = 512, drop1 = 0.3, drop2 = 0.3):
    input_word_ids = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32, name="input_word_ids")
    sequence_output = transformer(input_word_ids)[0]
    cls_token = sequence_output[:, 0, :]

    #Fine Tuning Model Start
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drop1)(cls_token)  
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drop2)(x)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(classes, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_word_ids, outputs=out)
    return model
```

Only useful thing I could get was in the `HuggingFace` that

> With the tight interoperability between TensorFlow and PyTorch models, you can even save the model and then reload it as a PyTorch model (or vice-versa)

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification

model.save_pretrained("my_imdb_model")
pytorch_model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained("my_imdb_model", from_tf=True)
```

So maybe I could train a `pytorch MLM` and then load it as a `tensorflow` fine tuned classification model?
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I think after some research, I found something. I don't know if it'll work but it uses `transformer` and `Tensorflow` with `XLM` . I think it'll work for `BERT` too.

```
PRETRAINED_MODEL = 'jplu/tf-xlm-roberta-large'
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import transformers
from transformers import TFAutoModelWithLMHead, AutoTokenizer

def create_mlm_model_and_optimizer():
    with strategy.scope():
        model = TFAutoModelWithLMHead.from_pretrained(PRETRAINED_MODEL)
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LR)
    return model, optimizer


mlm_model, optimizer = create_mlm_model_and_optimizer()




def define_mlm_loss_and_metrics():
    with strategy.scope():
        mlm_loss_object = masked_sparse_categorical_crossentropy

        def compute_mlm_loss(labels, predictions):
            per_example_loss = mlm_loss_object(labels, predictions)
            loss = tf.nn.compute_average_loss(
                per_example_loss, global_batch_size = global_batch_size)
            return loss

        train_mlm_loss_metric = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
        
    return compute_mlm_loss, train_mlm_loss_metric


def masked_sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_masked = tf.boolean_mask(y_true, tf.not_equal(y_true, -1))
    y_pred_masked = tf.boolean_mask(y_pred, tf.not_equal(y_true, -1))
    loss = tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true_masked,
                                                          y_pred_masked,
                                                          from_logits=True)
    return loss

            
            
def train_mlm(train_dist_dataset, total_steps=2000, evaluate_every=200):
    step = 0
    ### Training lopp ###
    for tensor in train_dist_dataset:
        distributed_mlm_train_step(tensor) 
        step+=1

        if (step % evaluate_every == 0):   
            ### Print train metrics ###  
            train_metric = train_mlm_loss_metric.result().numpy()
            print("Step %d, train loss: %.2f" % (step, train_metric))     

            ### Reset  metrics ###
            train_mlm_loss_metric.reset_states()
            
        if step  == total_steps:
            break


@tf.function
def distributed_mlm_train_step(data):
    strategy.experimental_run_v2(mlm_train_step, args=(data,))


@tf.function
def mlm_train_step(inputs):
    features, labels = inputs

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = mlm_model(features, training=True)[0]
        loss = compute_mlm_loss(labels, predictions)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, mlm_model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, mlm_model.trainable_variables))

    train_mlm_loss_metric.update_state(loss)
    

compute_mlm_loss, train_mlm_loss_metric = define_mlm_loss_and_metrics()
```

Now train it as `train_mlm(train_dist_dataset, TOTAL_STEPS, EVALUATE_EVERY)`

[Above ode is from this notebook and you need to do all the necessary things given exactly](https://www.kaggle.com/riblidezso/finetune-xlm-roberta-on-jigsaw-test-data-with-mlm)

The author says in the end that:

> This fine tuned model can be loaded just as the original to build a classification model from it